# Do I need A Different Sigset For Each C POSIX Thread To Ensure Atomicity When Masking Signals?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, unix, posix

If the signals that I want to mask and unmask are common between all threads, can I use one global variable for the signal set in POSIX C to pass to pthread_sigmask, or there should be different sigsets for each thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second argument of `pthread_sigmask()` is constant (`const sigset_t *set`) [meaning that the memory pointed by `set` will not be modified], so you can declare a single [possibly global, at your opinion] variable, without the need of implementing any thread locking mechanism while accessing it as it won't be modified. All threads will always read the same [consistent] value from it.

You can declare something like:

```
/* Global scope */
sigset_t g_set;
```

And pass it to `pthread_sigmask()`:

```
/* Assuming `g_set` is already properly set at this point and won't be modified in the future */
pthread_sigmask(how, &g_set, NULL);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I forgot to look up the parameters of pthread_sigmask, and see which ones are/are not constant. Anyways, thanks again for the reminder.